# Getting previous objects value in current object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using a dataset that contains around **65k data**. I am mapping over the dataset multiple times to massage the dataset. After obtaining the dataset in the required format, I am using map to do some computations with the price of the current item. But, whenever I return the current object, it contains the computation data of the previous object.

Whenever I log the data, it always shows the current object and the computations based on the current object. But, the returned object contains a previous object's data. Here is the route:

```
const {priceBands} = require('../utils/profitComputations');

let profitArray = [];

//calculating the price bands
profitArray = _.map(nfoArray, item=>{
     console.log(item.cmp);
     //returns the current market price; getting the correct value here

     let priceBandVar = priceBands(Number(item.cmp));
     console.log(priceBandVar);
     //applying some algorithms; getting the correct value here

     return {item: item.cmp, profitBand: priceBandVar};
     //Here I find a mismatch between the parameter and the calculations

});
```

Here is the priceBands function in my **'utils/profitComputations'**:

```
const _ = require('lodash');
 const priceBandInterval = {'-4':0, '-3':0, '-2':0, '-1':0, '0floor':0,'0ceil':0,'1':0, '2':0, '3':0, '4':0};
    let priceBands = {};
    module.exports = {
        priceBands: function(price){
            let factor = 0;
             if(price>=10000){
                    factor =  100;
                }else if (price>=1000 && price<10000){
                    factor = 50;
                }else if (price>=500 && price<1000){
                    factor = 25;
                }else if (price>=100 && price<500){
                    factor = 10;
                }else if(price>=25 && price<100){
                    factor = 2;
                }else{
                    factor = 0.5;
                }
             let priceCeil, priceFloor;
             if((price%factor) == 0){   
                priceCeil = price + factor;
                priceFloor = price - factor;
             } else {
                const remainder = price%factor;
                priceCeil = price - remainder + factor;
                priceFloor = price - remainder;
             }
            _.map(Object.keys(priceBandInterval), item=>{
                if(parseInt(item)>0){
                    priceBands[item] = (parseInt(item)*factor) + priceCeil;
                } else if (parseInt(item)<0){
                    priceBands[item] = (parseInt(item)*factor) + priceFloor;
                } else {
                    priceBands['0floor'] = priceFloor;
                    priceBands['0ceil'] = priceCeil;
                }
            });
            return priceBands;
        }
    }
```

I would appreciate if someone can share some valuable insights on what I am missing.

Comment: What is the scope of `priceBands` in the lower function? It doesn't look to be initialized anywhere? If you meant for every call of the function to result in a separate standalone object, you should initialize the `priceBrands` object *inside* that function, else it'll be persistent

Comment: I have actually initialized it at the top of the route like so: const {priceBands} = require('../utils/profitComputations')

Comment: About the lower function, it is actually in an utils.js file, which I am exporting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must clone the variable `priceBandVar` because javaScript variables are called by reference. The following code is your answer:

```
profitArray = _.map(nfoArray, item => {
  console.log(item.cmp);
  //returns the current market price; getting the correct value here

  let priceBandVar = priceBands(Number(item.cmp));
  console.log(priceBandVar);
  //applying some algorithms; getting the correct value here

  return {
    item: item.cmp,
    profitBand: clone(priceBandVar)
  };
  //Here I find a mismatch between the parameter and the calculations

});

function clone(o) {
  var ret = {};
  Object.keys(o).forEach(function(val) {
    ret[val] = o[val];
  });
  return ret;
}
```